# The field is not visible JAVA

Tags: java, oop, methods, field

I'm currently working on a program, and in my subclass, I need to have a no argument constructor that initializes the object with empty strings.

I've tried using super, I have setter and getter methods, but I keep getting "the field Person.name is not visible". I get this for address and phoneNumber as well.

How do I make it so it is visible, and I can initialize the objects without giving the constructor arguments? Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong and need to fix something (:

```
    // Create a class named Person
public class Person {
    
    // Fields: name, address, and phone number. (2 points)
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    // No argument constructor that initializes the object with empty strings for name, address, and phone. (2 points)
    public Person () {


        super();
        this.name = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.phoneNumber = "";

    }

    // 3 argument constructor that initializes the object with a name, address, and a phone number. (2 points)
    public Person2 (String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;


    }

    // Getter/setter methods for each of the fields. (3 points)

    // set/get name
    public void setName (String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName () {

        return this.name;
    }

    // set/get address
    public void setAddress (String address) {

        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress () {

        return this.address;
    }

    // set/get phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber (String phoneNumber) {


        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    }

    public String getPhoneNumber () {

        return this.phoneNumber;
    }


    // toString method that returns a string for the name, address, and phone number (2 points)
    // (you can override the toString method as part of a class which is pretty swag)
    public String toString() {

        return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Address: " + address + "\n" + "Phone: " + phoneNumber;

    }

}

// Create a subclass of Person named Customer
class Customer extends Person {

    // A field for a customer number. (1 point)
    private String customerNumber;

    public Customer () {
        
        //  A no argument constructor that initializes the object with an empty string for the name, address, phone, and customer number. (2 points)
        super(name, address, phoneNumber);

    }

    // A 4 argument constructor that initializes the object with a name, address, a phone number, and a customer number. (2 points)
    public Customer2 (String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String customerNumber) {
        
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;

    }

    // Getter/setter method for the customer number field. (1 point)
    public void setCustomerNumber (String customerNumber) {

        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;

    }

    // toString method that prints the information from the Person toString as well as the customer number (2 points) 
    public String toString() {

        return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Address: " + address + "\n" + "Phone: " + phoneNumber + "\n" + "Customer Number: " + customerNumber;

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you know access modifiers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I don’t understand the `Customer` no-arg ctor anyway; the `Person` no-arg ctor does exactly that already—it makes no sense to call the arg ctor when you don’t have args.

Comment: Not too well, but I've been told that it's best practice to keep variables private.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm building a program based of a set of instructions, which I've placed into my code through the comments :/

Comment: @Sherixn It would be clearer (and closer to the comment’s intent) to explicitly empty strings in the `super()` call if this is explicitly subclass behavior.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot access or assign to a `private` field in any other class than the one that it is declared in.
2. You cannot declare a constructor with any name other than the name of the class.  Thus `Person2` and `Customer2` are not neither valid constructors or valid methods.  (A method requires a return type!)
3. A constructor must explicitly (via a `super` call) or implicitly chain a no-args constructor in its superclass.

Basically, your choices for initializing a private field in a superclass are either use a `super(...)` call to chain the a superclass constructor passing the value OR call a superclass setter method within the subclass constructor.

For example, the 4 arg constructor in `Customer` could be:

```
public Customer (String name, String address, 
                 String phoneNumber, String customerNumber) {
    super(name, address, phoneNumber);
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}
```

or

```
public Customer (String name, String address, 
                 String phoneNumber, String customerNumber) {
    super();  // you could leave this out - it is implied
    setName(name);
    setAddress(address);
    setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}
```

IMO, the former is better.  It is more concise and more readable.

The `toString()` method in `Customer` cannot refer directly to the private fields of the `Person`.  It could use the fields' getters.

Comment: Thank you for all this information!!! So I should be naming the first 2 constructors Person and the 2 others Customer?

Comment: Yes.  You should.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I really appreciate the work you took into explaining everything and for being very kind in pointing out my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If a field is marked with private access then it can only be accessed from inside that class or instances of it. You should use the get methods. Or, you can get the result of `toString` and build on that.

Also, all constructors should have the same name as the class (no "2" added).

```
public class Person {
    
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person() {
        this("", "", "");
    }

    public Person(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setAddress (String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress () {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber (String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber () {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Address: " + address + "\n" + "Phone: " + phoneNumber;
    }
}

// Create a subclass of Person named Customer
class Customer extends Person {

    private String customerNumber;

    public Customer () {
        this("", "", "", "");
    }

    public Customer (String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String customerNumber) {
        super(name, address, phoneNumber);
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber (String customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\n" + "Customer Number: " + customerNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: tysm! I am so dumb for not realizing that you need to name constructors the same as the class

Comment: Thank you for also putting in that @Override for the toString, I forgot I needed to do that (:

Comment: You Don’t need to, but it shows intent. And if you add @Override and misspell the nam, or use wrong signature you will get an error. Much better than confusion of why you method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any actual need to call the super constructor in the person class. However, in the constructor for the costumer class, you should just call the super constructor with no arguments.

Edit: or you could initiate the values directly upon declaration, like the guy above me said.

PS. kinda unrelated, but, you could have one constructor but give the arguments default values. So you can call it with and without arguments with no need to override it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the snippet that you provided:

1. There is no need to define different names for constructors of the same class. The fact that their signature (i.e. set of input parameters) is different suffices.
2. Regarding your question, the error is that you're trying to access Person's private fields in the Customer's constructors directly. There are two ways to fix this issue:

- Change the Person fields' scope from private to **protected**. This will allow any class that inherits the Person class to access the aforementioned fields directly.
- When in Customer class, use the getter/setter methods to access the private fields.

Comment: Thank you for this information! Thank you for pointing out to use the getter/setter. (: